# Individual sizing of div while using flex

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I am using `display: flex` to create a responsive card-based dashboard.

[Fiddle here.](https://codepen.io/lpshreyas/pen/gxOGGQ?editors=1100)

I noticed that the cards (each individual element `div`) all shrink or expand vertically to maintain the same size when in a row. So, the height of the biggest (or highest) card is inherited by the rest of the cards in the same row.

> **Note:** When you resize the Fiddle window, you will notice this happens **only** when more than one card is present in a row. So, when the window is too small to allow only one card horizontally, the size is dependent on the content inside.

I can't seem to figure out which property is doing that so here's my question:

**How to get the cards to NOT get resized?**

OR

**How to retain the responsiveness without using `display: flex`**

Comment: You can add `align-items: flex-start;` on flex container but i think you want masonry for this.

Comment: Do you mean the css attribute 'flex' or the programming language? In case you don't mean the programming language, read the quickinfo of tag 'flex'.

Comment: @reporter - I am talking about css attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the cards to be resized, you should had `align-items: flex-start` on the flex container and remove the `min-height: 250px` on the cards. Maybe you can set `height: auto` on the cards

Comment: I need the `min-height` to make sure that the cards don't look weird when there's no content in them

Comment: Than make the min-height 120px

Comment: Actually, `align-items: flex-start` did the trick. Thanks